# Mysql concating multiple rows into one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, recursive-query

I was trying to take a string i-e 'hello'. Convert it into characters to so i can convert it into ascii code and then i concat it again but the problem is i am getting each character in a different row. Any idea how to merge them all in a single row. without any ',' or something in between them? Any help would be very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `group_concat()`, not `concat()` - along with option `separator ''`.

```
set @word = 'hello';

with recursive cte as (
    select @word as word, left(@word, 1) as val, 1 as idx
    union all
    select word, substring(word, idx + 1, 1), idx + 1 
    from cte 
    where idx < char_length(word)
)
select group_concat(ascii(val) order by idx separator '') ascii_word from cte
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I will surely approve your answer. I tried to do it now. But it did not allow me. Much appreciated.